# What workspace plan is needed for using Google Cloud Search API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-cloud-search

I am using "Google Workspace" with "Business Standard" plan.
I followed this guild to build a search interface
https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/query-guide

I stuck at Configure a search application because I couldn't find the place to create new Search Application in Workspace admin console.
Does Google Cloud Search API come with Business Standard Plan?

I tried using the api without search application but it said searchApplicationId is required.

By the way, I am able to use the web version of cloud search on https://cloudsearch.google.com/, but not the api

Comment: FYI this is off topic - it’s not a programming question.